# Unexpected ng-change Behavior

Tags: angularjs

Looking at an exercise from [AngularJS in Action](http://www.manning.com/bford/), I'm trying to implement the `ng-change` behavior to update the `select`'s drop-down value upon a change to the `story.status`.

**JS**

```
$scope.setCurrentStatus = function(status) { 
    if(typeof $scope.currentStory !== 'undefined') {
        $scope.currentStory.status = status.name;
    }
};

$scope.setCurrentStory = function(story) {
    $scope.currentStory = story
    $scope.currentStatus = $scope.statusesIndex[story.status];
    $scope.currentType = $scope.typesIndex[story.type];

    console.log("$scope.currentType", $scope.currentType);
};
```

Note that, when I select a story, the logging from `setCurrentStory` executes, but not `setCurrentStatus`.

**HTML**

```
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputType">Type</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select id="inputType"
                            ng-model="currentType"
                            ng-options="t.name for t in types"
                            ng-change="setCurrentType(currentType)"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/qLue3/1/

Comment: You're trying to set a property of an object that has a `null` value. If you look in the console you will see the following error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'status' of null`. If you change this line  `$scope.currentStory = null;` to this `$scope.currentStory = {};` it appears to correctly set the value of the status property.

Comment: Hmm, updating line 4 to `$scope.currentStory = {};` did not fix this issue for me. http://jsfiddle.net/qLue3/2/

Comment: Sorry I miss understood what you were asking, however when changing the value of the status select an error was being thrown. I am not sure that the `ng-change` will fire when changing the underlying value. If I understand it correctly, Only when the user actually changes the selection will the `ng-change` function fire.

Comment: I wonder why I didn't see that error. All that you did was change a select's drop-down value, and then you saw the error?